# Go to an activity from anywhere

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a login system. The user needs to be redirected to the login activity from any previous activity if the token is no longer valid. I can go to the login activity with this

```
new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
```

But this needs the current activity. I just want to go to the login activity no matter where I am. I cannot know where I am because this is inside an entirely different package.

Comment: put a check for your token in every activity you have and fire this intent from it

Comment: Won't that be repetitive. I already have a package that makes api calls, processes them, verifies the tokens, all the bells and whistles. Doesn't make sense to do it in every file again and again.

Comment: `But this needs the current activity.` what do you mean: "current activity"? it just needs a `Context` to `startActivity`, nothing more

Comment: How do I get the context? this is not in the main class of the activity. It's inside another package that is called from the main class.

Comment: you have to pass it somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably register in the Application class to [`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) and if the user is not registered send them to the correct Activity.

just be sure to not endlessly send them from the login page to itself

*EDIT:*
adding some code and explanation.

In order to figure out if an Activity that shouldn't be alive is going through lifecycle events you'll need to implement some sort of a gate keeper. Previously it used to be some sort of static state that is kept in the Application class and holds the current activity and sometime even the stack of current activities.

This was far from a complete solution and had issues due to different tasks and even isolated procesies.

In API 14 Android introduced the Activity lifecycle callbacks which can be passed into the method [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)) int the `Application` class.

What you want to do basically is the following:

```
class ThepooshApplication extends Application {

    private static sIsRegistered = false;

    public static setIsRegistered(boolean isRegistered) { sIsRegistered = isRegistered; }

    public void onCreate() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks(){
            @Override
            void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState){
                if (!sIsRegistered && !(activity instanceof LoginActivity)) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }
            @Override
            void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) { /*empty method*/ }
            @Override
            void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) { /*empty method*/ }
            @Override
            void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) { /*empty method*/ }
            @Override
            void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) { /*empty method*/ }
            @Override
            void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) { /*empty method*/ }
            @Override
            void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) { /*empty method*/ }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do exactly? A quick google search doesn't seem to bring up any concrete explanation. The docs are sparse on text too.

Answer (score 1):

You must add  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag to your intent

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Try some like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this,TestActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Replace TestActivity.class for your target activity

Comment: Tasks seem like the way to go but is it appropriate for the use case? Task is supposed to be something entirely separate. Here I want to send user to log in.